# Subtracting one column from another column in different tables to leave the answer in another column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert, mamp

[m_type table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7W9hg.png)
[membership table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hZaS.png)

I have a membership table with amount paid, amount due. I also have a m_type table with price . 
 I want a trigger so that when a row is inserted or updated into the membership table WHERE membership.type_id = m_type.type-id that the price column from the m_type table is subtracted away from the amount_paid column in the membership table and the answer is put into the amount_due column in the membership table.
Thanks

What i have currently tried:
[What i have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSORu.png)

Comment: You should leave your code the way it was!!!  It is annoying to have to look at a picture with code.

Comment: Thanks will note that for future use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER amount_due_cal BEFORE INSERT ON membership
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    SET NEW.amount_due := (
        SELECT price FROM m_type WHERE type_id = New.type_id) - NEW.amount_paid;
END $$    
DELIMITER ;
```

If this doesn't work let me know.

Also note that `type_id` needs to be a unique index / primary key for the `price` table or this won't work.

Comment: Thanks i understand that part. It worked perfectly!